# Creating an axis with selected numbers and equal spacing in Oxyplot with WPF

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

For a graph one axis needs to have selected numbers with equal spacing.
The numbers are in order but with different gaps, Example 1, 2, 5, 100, 2000.
I managed to get the selected numbers by overriding the GetTickValues method.
These are now spaced out according to value, how can I instead have equal spacing between these ticks regardless of the actual value?

I have tried changing the majorTickValues and majorLabelsValues but those seem to be independent from each other.

Comment: Graphing is usually about X,Y locations.  If you have 4 points to graph and for those make X 1, 2, 3, 4 then each point is going to be equally placed along the X axis.

Comment: Yes, these numbers correspond to another axis so I cannot alter them. I want to display the correlation between two sets of numbers but the size difference between the numbers in one of the set does not matter in this case.

Comment: I still don't quite follow why you're not altering the size difference that doesn't matter, leaving the one that does matter. Alter Y if you can't change X.

Comment: Think of it like I have pairs of numbers to display x: y example 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 2000. With size difference I mean that the difference between 2, 5 and 2000 in my example doesn't matter so there is no point in showing it by having 2000 far off to the side. The function is to quickly find the number correlating to the one you have. I realize a table would be a better display but a line graph has been ordered and I have to implement it.

Comment: What you're saying is that the values for Y do not matter. Make them 1,2,3. They are then evenly spaced and you're saying the difference doesn't matter.  Why is making these 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3 a problem?

Comment: I found a solution to this with a categoryaxis that solved my problem. I'm sorry I was unable to describe my problem. Maybe think of it like a if you have X you need to add Y problem. But Y follows no common progression and we don't have values for all X:s. Both values still matter because you need to able to go "okay I got X=3 how much should i add of Y".